# .htaccess - slim framwork in 1and1 throws 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm facing 404 error using slim framework with 1and1 hosting.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

tried all answers but not working. help me to get rid of this.

my path is

```
/api/users
```

and URL is

```
domain.com/api/users/register
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? At `/api/users/.htaccess`? Where does `%{ENV:BASE}` come from?

Comment: yes, `.htaccess` file at `/api/users/.htaccess`. i'm not aware of `.htaccess` fully

Comment: Try removing `%{ENV:BASE}` from the `RewriteRule` directive.